# R RSQLite Couldn't find driver SQLite

Tags: r, rsqlite

I'm trying the following.

```
library(RSQLite)
library(DBI)
drv <- dbDriver("SQLite")

Error: Couldn't find driver SQLite. Looked in:
* global namespace
* in package called SQLite
* in package called RSQLite
```

help please!

Comment: This is not a question.

Comment: Instead of `dbDriver("SQLite")`, can you use `RSQLite::SQLite()`?

Comment: I get the following message ```Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'blob' ```I tried installing blob package but that also gives me a long error message and at the end this ```Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package 'blob' had non-zero exit status```