# installation of dbDriver package in linux using conda

Tags: r, linux, error-handling, package, conda

I am trying to install dbDriver package in linux using conda but its showing error.
The command used:

```
conda install -c r r-dbi
```

The script which require this package(first few lines):

```
#!/bin/R
"%&%" <- function(a,b) paste(a,b, sep='')
driver <- dbDriver('SQLite')
model_summaries <- read.table('/home/Model_training_chr22_model_summaries.txt',header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

The error:
Error in dbDriver("SQLite") : could not find function "dbDriver"
Execution halted
(train)

Comment: Did you maybe forget `library(DBI)` at the beginning of your script?

Comment: I tried this but its still shows the error.The error: Error: Couldn't find driver SQLite. Looked in:
* global namespace
* in package called SQLite
* in package called RSQLite
Execution halted

Comment: maybe this can help from there on? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58961930/r-rsqlite-couldnt-find-driver-sqlite